# How to resolve the problem RecyclerView not showing on the screen wih viewBinding and unable to call any Adapter methods except getItemCount()?

Tags: android, kotlin

RecyclerView Unable to call any Adapter function except getItemCount() in Kotlin

I wanted to get recyclerview for my fragment and it doesn't show any errors but i can't see my recyclerview on my screen

**fragment_contacts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".contacts.Contacts">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/contactCardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation_cardView"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:queryHint="@string/search_placeholder" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/contactCardView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**each_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation_cardView">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/constraint_padding">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/square_card_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/square_card_size"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_pfp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/no_profile"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:contentDescription="@string/user_pfp" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/enter_your_name"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_sz"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_aboutMe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/about_profile"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_sz"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**Contacts.kt**

```
package com.example.chatty.contacts

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.chatty.ContactsAdapter
import com.example.chatty.UserListData
import com.example.chatty.databinding.FragmentContactsBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class Contacts : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentContactsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding
    private lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var userArrayList: ArrayList<UserListData>
    private lateinit var myAdapter: ContactsAdapter
    private lateinit var fStore: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var fAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentContactsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding?.root

        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context as Activity)
        binding?.recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)

        userArrayList = arrayListOf()

        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        fStore.collection("users").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            if(!it.isEmpty){
                val userList = it.documents
                for(i in userList){
                    if(i.id != fAuth.currentUser?.uid){
                        val user = UserListData(i.getString("Name").toString(), i.getString("About").toString(), i.getString("userProfilePhoto").toString())
                        userArrayList.add(user)
                        myAdapter = ContactsAdapter(context as Activity, userArrayList)
                        binding?.recyclerView?.adapter = myAdapter
                        binding?.recyclerView?.layoutManager = layoutManager
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("onFound", "This is user Account")
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        return view
    }

}
```

**ContactsAdapter.kt**

```
package com.example.chatty

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class ContactsAdapter(val context: Context, private val userList: ArrayList<UserListData>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.MyViewHolder> (){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.each_item, parent, false)
        Log.d("Adapter", "myHolderView set")
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.d("Holder", "Holder set")
        val user: UserListData = userList[position]
        holder.userName.text = user.Name
        holder.userAbout.text = user.About
        Picasso.get().load(user.userProfilePhoto).placeholder(R.drawable.no_profile).error(R.drawable.no_profile).into(holder.userProfile)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val userProfile: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_pfp)
        val userName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name)
        val userAbout: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_aboutMe)
    }
}
```

Data Class **UserListData.kt**

```
package com.example.chatty

public data class UserListData(val Name: String ?= null, val About: String ?= null, val userProfilePhoto: String ?= null)
```

**MenuActivity.kt** parent activity of Contacts fragment

```
package com.example.chatty

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.chatty.about.About
import com.example.chatty.contacts.Contacts
import com.example.chatty.databinding.ActivityMenuBinding
import com.example.chatty.settings.Settings

class MenuActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMenuBinding
    private lateinit var optionValue: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMenuBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Chatty)
        setContentView(view)
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.greyTint)

        if(intent != null){
            optionValue = intent.getStringExtra("OptionName").toString()
            when (optionValue){
                "Settings" -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, Settings()).commit()
                    binding.toolbarMenu.title = "Settings"
                }
                "About" -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, About()).commit()
                    binding.toolbarMenu.title = "About Us"
                }
                "Contacts" -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, Contacts()).commit()
                    binding.toolbarMenu.title = "Contacts"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried my times in different ways but none of them worked. Got any idea what's the problem here?

Comment: Make sure your `RecyclerView` is actually being displayed - you can use the *Layout Inspector* after running your app to see an outline of where your Views are, so make sure it's occupying some space on the screen. Then make sure you're actually setting the Adapter with some non-empty data - right now you're relying on getting data from your Firebase calls, try adding an Adapter with some test data during setup instead. That way you can see if your Adapter works, and if it does, your problem is probably with what you get back from Firebase

Comment: @cactustictacs i did what you told me to check but nothing changed